# Getting table-tools CKEditor plugin to work in Drupal

Tags: drupal, plugins, drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-modules

I am attempting to set up a table for a client with minimal html experience. I was hoping that CKEditor would have an innate "Add row" feature but it does not. Then I learned about Table Tools -- I am hoping to add this to my install but Drupal 7 does not integrate the plugins properly, even though I see them in the CKEditor admin section. You can see what I am speaking of in the image attached.

What could I be doing wrong? Upon downloading the plugins CKeditor told me to add config.extraPlugins = 'dialog'; config.extraPlugins = 'tabletools'; config.extraPlugins = 'tableresize'; config.extraPlugins = 'contextmenu';

But I am not quite sure this is necessary in Drupal. Is it? And where would I go?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using the official [CKEditor for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, check the documentation: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Plugins

Answer (score 2):

Like most other editors (MS-Word, etc.), CKEditor can add a new row if you go to the last cell of the table and hitting [Tab]. No need for fancy plugins!

Comment: Wow man, thanks. I was hitting enter the entire time. Appreciate it.

Comment: In case it doesn't work for someone – AFAIR this functionality is implemented by the `tab` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Table tools](http://doksoft.com/soft/ckeditor-table-tools/index.html) plugin. It is big add-on with many tools, for example add row, add column, editing cell, etc. Also you can create your own styles and classes in table configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> config.extraPlugins = 'dialog'; config.extraPlugins = 'tabletools'; config.extraPlugins = 'tableresize'; config.extraPlugins = 'contextmenu';

This code is not going to work. In JavaScript this is a simple assignment, so only the last value will be used. Therefore, you need to join these plugins names:

```
 config.extraPlugins = 'dialog,tabletools,tableresize,contextmenu';
```